# How can I get this ComboBox to bind, populate the dropdown and write back selected value on update?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I've tried everything to get a comboBox to retrieve a value from my database upon load and the update it. If there's a value in the column, comboBox should be filled with the selection. If it's null then pick from a list (Ey/Manual or Accepted/Rejected) and update the value when update command is called. Could someone point me in the right direction? No matter how much I try, the comboBox stays empty after the load and if I manage to write to the db it's this format instead of the value: `"System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Accepted"`

Current behavior: the comboBox doesn't return and set the value after the load. Desired outcome: return value from db and set the comboBox to it. Also if I select a different value (Accepted/Rejected) and update, it will write the comboBox value to the db correctly without the entire string suffix "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem:"

**XAML:**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
        x:Class="BillingStatus.MainWindow"
        x:Name="BillingStatus"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"     
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BillingStatus"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:BillingStatus.ViewModel">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:BillingStatusViewModel/>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>


    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="20,211,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding BillingStatusItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBillingStatusItem}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Label Content="Reviewed By:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="25" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ReviewedBy, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                            <Label Content="Upload Type:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="25" />
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UploadTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUploadType, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            </ComboBox>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using BillingStatus.ViewModel;

namespace BillingStatus
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new BillingStatusViewModel();

        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataContext is BillingStatusViewModel viewModel)
            {
                // Get the selected item from the view model
                BillingStatusItem selectedItem = viewModel.SelectedBillingStatusItem;

                // Call the UpdateRecordInDatabase method with the selected item
                UpdateRecordInDatabase(selectedItem);

                viewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }



        private void UpdateRecordInDatabase(BillingStatusItem item)
        {
             
            // Check if Location is provided and not null or empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Location))
            {
                Messagebox.Show();
                return;
            }

            string connectionString = "data Source=; initial catalog=; user id=; password=";
            string updateQuery = "UPDATE ReviewedBy = @reviewedBy, UploadType = @uploadType WHERE Location = @location";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, connection);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", item.Location);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reviewedBy", (object)item.ReviewedBy ?? DBNull.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploadType", (object)item.SelectedUploadType ?? DBNull.Value);             

                // Set parameter types explicitly
                cmd.Parameters["@location"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                cmd.Parameters["@reviewedBy"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                cmd.Parameters["@uploadType"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (rowsAffected > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;

namespace BillingStatus.ViewModel
{
    public class BillingStatusViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<string> _locations;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Locations
        {
            get { return _locations; }
            set
            {
                _locations = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Locations));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<BillingStatusItem> _billingStatusItems;
        public ObservableCollection<BillingStatusItem> BillingStatusItems
        {
            get { return _billingStatusItems; }
            set
            {
                _billingStatusItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BillingStatusItems));
            }
        }

        private BillingStatusItem _selectedBillingStatusItem;
        public BillingStatusItem SelectedBillingStatusItem
        {
            get { return _selectedBillingStatusItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedBillingStatusItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedBillingStatusItem));
            }
        }


        private ObservableCollection<string> _uploadTypes;
        public ObservableCollection<string> UploadTypes
        {
            get { return _uploadTypes; }
            set
            {
                _uploadTypes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UploadTypes));
            }
        }
        
        public BillingStatusViewModel()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        public void LoadData()
        {
            string connectionString = "data Source=; initial catalog=; user id=; password=";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location, LocationStatus, ReviewedBy, " +
                                                 "UploadType, " +
                                                 "FROM dbo.BillingStatus WHERE LocationStatus = 'Open'", connection);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    // Initialize collections
                    Locations = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                    BillingStatusItems = new ObservableCollection<BillingStatusItem>();
                    UploadTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

();

```
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string location = reader.GetString(0);
                        Locations.Add(location);
                        string locationStatus = reader.GetString(1);
                        string uploadType = reader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : reader.GetString(7);

                        // Add distinct upload types
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadType) && !UploadTypes.Contains(uploadType))
                            UploadTypes.Add(uploadType);
                        string reviewedBy = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : reader.GetString(6);

                        BillingStatusItem newItem = new BillingStatusItem
                        {
                            Location = location,
                            LocationStatus = locationStatus,
                            ReviewedBy = reviewedBy,
                            SelectedUploadType = uploadType,
                        };

                        BillingStatusItems.Add(newItem);
                    }

                    reader.Close(); // Close the reader when done
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }



    public class BillingStatusItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _location;
        public string Location
        {
            get { return _location; }
            set
            {
                _location = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Location));
            }
        }

        private string _locationStatus;
        public string LocationStatus
        {
            get { return _locationStatus; }
            set
            {
                _locationStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationStatus));
            }
        }

        private string _reviewedBy;
        public string ReviewedBy
        {
            get { return _reviewedBy; }
            set
            {
                _reviewedBy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReviewedBy));
            }
        }

        private string _selectedUploadType;
        public string SelectedUploadType
        {
            get { return _selectedUploadType; }
            set
            {
                _selectedUploadType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUploadType));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem. What code is problematic? Would you please remove all unnecessary code so that only the code (XAML and C#) is left that is required to reproduce the behavior? A minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Just pasting everything you have in is easy for you to do but makes it hard for anyone else to understand and reproduce your issue. You should debug through.  You should, however, be binding the combobox items source and NOT add items in xaml as you are doing. That's one problem I can see.

Comment: You should use dapper ( or some other micro orm) to reduce the amount of repetitive code necessary for database access. I also recommend the community mvvm toolkit.

Comment: @Sir Rufo I've just updated my questions. BionicCode: the comboBox is problematic, it doesn't return any value and I can't get it to update correctly either. I just trimmed down the code. Andy: I appreciate the suggestion but everything is working well for me except the comboBox. Could you please help with an answer? Can you explain this part further:  "You should, however, be binding the combobox items source and NOT add items in xaml as you are doing. That's one problem I can see."